# Strip whatever is in () at the end of string

Tags: php, regex

I have a text string:

```
$str = "This is my string (something else)";
```

The string may or may not have something in ( ), but if it does, I need to strip it entirely. I tried this:

```
$new = str_replace('/\\(.*/', '', $str);
```

But it does not seem to work... What am I missing?

Comment: `str_replace()` does not operate on regular expressions. [`preg_replace()` does](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$new = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/', '', $str);
```

Comment: This will replace the contents of _all_ parentheses in a string, not only those at the end.  Anchor the end with `$` to make sure only the last set is replaced.